# Which Thermal Pads would my Aorus RX 580 need?

Tags: cooling, thermal-pads

I've bought a used RX 580 which had thermal issues and it kept crashing at start which I fixed with replacing the thermal paste but while doing it I noticed that some of the pads were weird and some were torn for some reason.

Now after a while it's on 77C - 3000RPM and it sounds like a jet engine on full load so I am suspecting that the pads are low quality or useless at this point as well.

I've been looking at some thermal pads but I am unsure which thicknesses and how much to buy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need thermal transfer pads AND thermal paste. Your paste may now be acting as an insulator. I would start again, remove the pads, clean the surfaces with decontaminant and isopropyl alcohol (purer the better), apply new paste as per the die spec and put it all back together. You need to be quite sparing with thermal paste, it's very easy to apply too much.

Comment: Alright I'll go ahead and try again. How much thermal paste would I need on a gpu then in this case? I can't really tell that well when there is "too much".